# macOS Sierra opencv3 installation - "extra" modules not found

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to install opencv-3.1.0 on macOS Sierra. After running the following:

```
brew install opencv3 --HEAD --with-contrib
```

it returns:

```
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

opencv3 and opencv install many of the same files.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/opencv3/include
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/pkgconfig
```

and I can import opencv from Python level but it looks like that "extra" modules are not installed, specifically I need SIFT

```
    sift = cv2.SIFT()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIFT'
```

any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I *think* it's in `xfeatures2d` under `cv2`.

Comment: I missed it somehow... now it works, thank you!